# Pass a function as parameter in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters, anonymous

I would like to pass to a jQuery function a regular function, instead of the usual anonymous function, but I'm not sure how such a thing could be done.

Instead of this:

```
function setVersion(feature) {
      $.post("some.php", { abc:"abc" },
      function(data){
         // do something here
      }, "json");
}
```

I would like to do this:

```
function foo(data){
   // do something here
}

function setVersion(feature) {
      $.post("some.php", { abc:"abc" }, foo, "json");
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Ummm... run that.

Comment: Yep. That should work exactly as you want. Give it a try ;)

Comment: LOL, my bad, I tried to run `"foo"`, didn't bother to run it as just `foo`... And then I forgot the "" in the question :) I need to get some sleep!!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yeah, already works. But you want it probably look like this:

```
function setVersion(feature, myFunction) {
      $.post("some.php", { abc:"abc" }, myFunction, "json");
}
setVersion(blah, foo);
```

Answer (score 2):

Should run just fine.

I believe jQuery is actually meant to use the regular function, called by name.  Using the anonymous function is simply a replacement for a named function that would otherwise be passed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is exactly how you do it.